# 'Object' is to {worksheet, collection, class} as 'Variant' is to {string, integer, array}?

Tags: vba

I've recently discovered the joys of classes in VBA (with the assistance, in part, of some posts here), and wrote myself 2, one of which gets external data, and another which processes data.

The external data class executes SQL statements against data stores, or creates a QueryTable against an external file, depending on what I'm trying to achieve.

Thus, I declared the main function to return a `Variant` data-type, so that I can either return a collection of the retrieved record-sets or a reference to the worksheet that the QueryTable is written to.

The other class has several functions which expect a collection as an argument.

All this is to say that despite a Variant being able to store a collection, when I attempted to pass this to my Collection function, I received an error.

Looking at the 'Locals' window, I noticed that the return was actually `Variant/Object/Collection`, so just to see what would happen, I changed the return type to `Object`, and it seems to work for both Worksheets and Collections.

I've read the MSDN articles for both Variant and Object but I don't feel any closer to knowing whether the solution I've stumbled on is actually workable/reliable.

Does anyone have any knowledge of this?

Comment: Is there a reason to return a `Variant` at all?  Why not split your main function into multiple functions that return the strongly typed objects?

Comment: The idea is that the class has a single method called "getExternalData" which executes private functions to either create an ADO connection, or create a queryTable, or potentially other retrieval methods in future. So while the private functions are strongly typed, this method is not

Comment: That class design actually sounds extremely brittle, and that type of interface moves too much of what should be a class responsibility to the caller. Does the class itself work as intended?

Comment: Yes, it's working. Only when I attempted to pass the returned collection to another function I discovered that, while the variant contained a collection, it wasn't actually a collection. I could access it as a collection, but not pass it as such to another sub/function in another class. Now that I'm using object instead of variant for the return, I can pass the collection (or worksheet) around. Could you please explain what you mean by 'that type of interface moves too much of what should be a class responsibility to the caller'? As I said, I'm new to the whole idea of classes

Comment: Since it works, I'd suggest posting the entire class on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) (it's better suited to this discussion). By the interface comment I mean that without any other knowledge of the class other than its interfaces, the caller can't tell what the outcome of a function call will be.  That means the caller has to determine what is returned before the return value can be used.

Comment: In general, classes should have clearly defined interfaces with predictable behavior.

Comment: My question is actually about the use of an 'Object' variable as a place-holder in the same way that 'Variant' can be used for simpler data-types. I'm not sure that I'm ready, yet, to have my code torn apart on Code Review :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123995/discussion-between-comintern-and-emjaysx).